# Rebus with MSMQ: Erratic delivery-time

Tags: rebus

We're using Rebus with MSMQ for message-based communication between application components. The components are all running on the same machine.

The time between sending and receiving of messages usually stays below one second. But if the system is idle for a minute or so (meaning that no messages are being sent), the next one or two messages sometimes take around five seconds to be delivered. The MSMQ performance counters show that these messages stay in the queue during that time.

For our application it is desirable that messages have a constant delivery time (below one second).

What could be the reason for this behaviour?
Is there a way to influence the delivery time of messages in MSMQ or in Rebus?
Should we choose another transport type to get more stable delivery times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rebus will by default gradually back off its polling of the queues according to the timespans in [BackoffBehavior](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Configuration/BackoffBehavior.cs) - as you can see, it will end up polling the queue every 5 seconds if it stays idle for long enough.

You can change to the low-latency backoff strategy by going

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Behavior(b => b. SetLowLatencyBackoffBehavior())
    .(...)
```

in the configuration spell.

---

Update: In later versions of Rebus (i.e. version >= 2) the back-off times can be customized like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => {
        o.SetBackoffTimes(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        );
    })
```

in this case polling with 100 ms and 200 ms interval for the first two seconds of running idle, and then with 1 s interval for the rest of the time.

If this level of customization is not enough, the `ISyncBackoffStrategy` can be implemented and used by going `o.Register<ISyncBackoffStrategy>(c => new YourOwn SyncBackoffStrategy())` in the `.Options` configurer above.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, when Rebus notices that there are no messages in queue, it gradually increases the number of seconds it waits before it peeks the next time.

The 5 seconds you mention seems to correspond nicely with what I have experienced earlier as maximum wait time when I have been running Rebus with logging in DEBUG-mode (where you can see, that it increases the timespan).